# What to check in a test method that doesn't modify or return a value?

Tags: apex, unit-test, pmd

I have a queueable class that gets a token then enqueues another queueable with the retrieved token. The second queueable do the DML and everything.
This `TokenQueueable` class doesn't modify or return a value.

```
public class TokenQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    private Id objectId;

    public TokenQueueable(Id objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    // in the actual class we have try-catch and correct values etc. 
    // I tried to simplify it for the sake of this question
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        HttpResponse res = Util.postCallOut('test.example.com', 'payload');
        TokenResponse result = (TokenResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), TokenResponse.class);
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
            System.enqueueJob(new LeadQueueable(objectId, result.access_token, result.token_type));
        }
    }

    public class TokenResponse { 
        public String access_token;
        public String token_type;
        public String issued_at;
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement PMD in our org. As you know, it shows a warning if a test class doesn't have any assertions.
My question is, for testing of this class, is there anything I can check/assert or should I suppress the warning here?

Not sure if this is relevant but here is the test class as well.

```
@isTest 
static void tokenTest() {

    String html = TestDataFactory.getTokenResponse();
    MockHttpResponseGenerator token = new MockHttpResponseGenerator(200, 'OK', html, new Map<String, String>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'});
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, token);

    Test.startTest();
    System.enqueueJob(new TokenQueueable('000000000000000AAA'));
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to call the `execute()` method synchronously instead of having it go through `system.enqueueJob()`. Sure, the class may be executed async in the real world, but you're trying to test your class here (and not the Salesforce-provided async call handler).

If you only have a queueable chain 2 levels deep (i.e. if `LeadQueueable` itself doesn't chain another queueable), then you can remove the `if (!Test.isRunningTest()){` that guards the `system.enqueueJob()` for `LeadQueuable`.

Instead of doing that, you could simply continue to call chained queueable classes synchronously.

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest()){
    // enqueue when not running in a test context
    system.enqueueJob(new LeadQueueable());
}else{
    // otherwise, just call the execute() method synchronously
    new LeadQueueable().execute(null);
}
```

That alone doesn't get you anything that you can assert against though (any tangible output would be from `LeadQueueable` and thus something to be asserted in the `LeadQueueable` test class).

If you modify `TokenQueueable` so that you can inject the "next step" it should chain, then you could create a stub/mock queueable class (as an inner class of your test class, for example) and assert that the "next step" has its execute() method called.

e.g.

```
public class MyQueueable implements Queueable{
    Queueable nextStep;

    public void setNextStep(Queueable next){
        nextStep = next;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext){
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            system.enqueueJob(nextStep);
        }else{
            nextStep.execute(null);
        }
    }
}

@isTest
private class MyQueueableTest{
    public class MyNextQueueable implements Queueable{
        public Integer timesCalled = 0;

        public void execute(QueueableContext ctx){
            timesCalled++;
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testNextIsCalled(){
        MyQueueable mq = new MyQueueable();
        MyNextQueueable next = new MyNextQueueable();

        mq.setNextStep(next);

        Test.startTest();
        mq.execute(null);
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(1, next.timesCalled, 'Expected the next step to be called once');
    }
}
```